# Pig base 64 encoding/ store single line per record / remove newlines

Tags: apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I am trying to store some pig tuples data one per line to be later processed by an external system.

One of my fields is a bytearray representing a not-so-well structured html, containing newlines.

I tried using `REPLACE($0.raw,'(\r\n|\n|\t)',''))`, to no avail, as it requires chararray and returns errors when I tried to cast it.

Compressing the tuple, as long it would guarantee a single line, would solve my problem.

Is there an easy way to make sure that a record will be stored in a single line (except for writing a custom UDF, although an already existing one would be perfect)?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I implemented a custom UDF to convert bytearray to base64, which I then applied to the culprit field via standard `res = FOREACH parsed GENERATE my.little.pony.udf.package.ByteArrayToByteArrayB64($0.raw);`

The UDF definition:

```
package my.little.pony.udf.package;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray;

public class ByteArrayToByteArrayB64 extends EvalFunc<DataByteArray> {
    public DataByteArray exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
        return null;
        try{
            if (input.size() < 1){
                throw new IOException("Input is of size:"+input.size());
            }       

            DataByteArray data = (DataByteArray)input.get(0);
            String convertedBase64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data.get()); 
            return new DataByteArray(convertedBase64.getBytes("UTF-8"));


        }catch (ClassCastException e){
             throw new IOException("Tuple element at is really of type:"+input.get(0).getClass().getName());
        }catch(Exception e){
             throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
         }
    }
}
```